# Bash shell launched by forkpty() spawns child processes that ignore SIGINT. Why and how do I ensure SIGINT is not ignored?

Tags: bash, shell, c, signals, pty

I have a C program that uses forkpty to execute a bash shell.  I'm finding that the programs launched by this shell are launched with SIGINT ignored, so when I send a Ctrl-C to the shell they never close.

example:

```
int masterFd;
char* args[] = {"/bin/bash", "-i", NULL };
int procId = forkpty(&masterFd, NULL, NULL,  NULL);
if( procId == 0 ){
  execve( args[0], args, NULL);
}
else {
   // Simple code that reads from standard in and writes to masterFd.  
   // I also register for Ctrl-C and write it to masterFd if caught
}
```

Other control characters seem to make it through, ctrl-D, ctrl-? etc.  However, whenever I look at the status of a process launched by the new bash shell it appears as if SIGINT is masked out.

```
MyShell:# sleep 1000

StandardTerm:#  ps -ef | grep sleep
root    26611  19278  0  17:44  pts/1   00:00:00 sleep 1000
root    26613  32376  0  17:44  pts/1   00:00:00 grep sleep

StandardTerm:# grep Sig proc/26611/status
SigQ:    0/256428
SigPnd:  0000000000000000
SigBlk:  0000000000000000
SigIgn:  0000000000010006   <- THE 6 IS THE PROBLEM
SigCgt:  0000000180000000
```

SigIgn has the 2 bit set, which means 2 (SIGINT) is ignored.  if I do the exact same thing, but run sleep (or cat a giant file or whatever) in a standard terminal, this bit is cleared.  What am I doing when I launch my pty bash that is causing it to create grandchildren programs with SIGINT ignored?

Moreover, if I send a SIGINT signal to the process

```
StandardTerm:# kill -2 26611
```

nothing happens.  What's strange is when I send the same command to the bash shell I forkpty'ed IT works, because that bash shell is not ignoring SIGINT.

Answer (score 3):

maybe you just need to do:

```
stty sane
```

I notice that the [`forkpty()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/forkpty) `man` page says it will copy the termios settings of *`*termp`* to the newly opened pty, but it doesn't specifically say what it does with these otherwise, and the only not-NULL arg you hand `forkpty()` is for the pty master fd. I would guess you'd wind up with an entirely NULL termios structure, which can't be very useful. It wouldn't bother `bash` terribly which has got `readline()` to handle all its own terminal stuff, and so it would interpret all of the default characters by default anyhow.

here's a blockquote from a pretty informative [article](https://blog.nelhage.com/2009/12/a-brief-introduction-to-termios-termios3-and-stty/) on the subject:

> `stty`'s `-F` option can be great for peeking at what some other program is doing to its terminal. If you run `tty` in a shell, it will print the path to that shell's terminal device *(usually of the form `/dev/pts/N`, at least under Linux)*. Now, from a different shell, you can run `stty -a -F /dev/pts/N` to see how the first shell's terminal is configured. You can then run programs in the first shell, and repeat the `stty` incant in shell two to see what settings are getting set. For example, if I run `stty -F /dev/pts/10` right now *(while I have a `bash` talking to a `gnome-terminal` via that pty)*, I see:

```
    $ stty -F /dev/pts/10
      speed 38400 baud; line = 0;
      eol = M-^?; eol2 = M-^?; swtch = M-^?; lnext = <undef>; min = 1; time = 0;
     -icrnl iutf8
     -icanon -echo
```

> So we can see that `bash/readline` has disabled *`CR→LF`* translation on input *(`icrnl`)*, disabled *`canonical`* mode and *`echo`*, but turned on UTF-8 mode *(because `bash` detected a utf-8 locale)*. Note that if I run `stty` directly in that shell, I see something slightly different:

```
     $ stty
       speed 38400 baud; line = 0;
       eol = M-^?; eol2 = M-^?; swtch = M-^?;
       iutf8
```

> This is because `bash` maintains its own set of `termios` settings *(for `readline`)*, and saves and restores settings around running programs, so that settings in place while running a program are different from those in place while you're typing at the `bash` prompt.

Comment: That doesn't seem to do it.  Additionally, I looked into the parameters set by the PTY using tcgetattr() and they are identical to standard shells that DO work.

Comment: @djc6535 - you did your check while some other process was reading the terminal  right? like you did `cat` in your bg'd `bash` and then did `stty -F/dev/pts/[pty] -a` from another terminal or something, right?

Comment: I ran the stty while cat > /dev/null was running

Comment: @djc6535 - then i dunno. i did notice the related [`shellout()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/shellout) function indicates that default terminal settings are likely *unsuitable for interactive use* - whatever that means - and i suspected something similar might be going on with you.

Answer (score 0):

This outcome cannot be due to the code block you showed in your question. There must be something else in other parts of your overall setup.

Given only the usage scenario you described, the most likely reason is that you actually set SIGINT to be ignored in your code somewhere *before* the forkpty, or *before* the execve in forkpty’s child.

This would yield the outcome you describe because then your forkpty’ed `bash -i` would inherit such SIGINT-ignored setup, and while it would set it otherwise for its own internal purposes (thus not ignoring SIGINT) it would also reset it to the inherited ignored state for each and every command it would spawn.

This is documented Bash’s behavior, see Bash’s man-page at “COMMAND EXECUTION ENVIRONMENT” chapter, specifically the paragraph saying:

> When a simple command other than a builtin or shell function is to be executed, it is invoked in a separate execution environment that consists of the following. [...]
>
> [...]
>
> o      traps  caught  by the shell are reset to the values inherited from the shell's parent, and traps ignored by the shell are ignored

HTH